# VBA html option select and input

Tags: html

I´m completely new at working with VBA and html and I hope someone could help me.

In the website that I need to get information there´s a dropdown list and an input box which changes according to the option selected in the droplist.

With my VBA I´m able to make the dropdown list option change, but the input box wont change, it stays the same as the default option.

This is the code I´m running

```
Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HMTLInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "myURL"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

HTMLDoc.getElementById("zkComp62").Click

HTMLDoc.getElementById("zkComp66").Click

Set seleccion = HTMLDoc.getElementById("zkComp118")
seleccion.selectedIndex = 3
```

and this is the hmtl code that I get from the website if I run the code

```html
<table id="tblFiltros">  <tbody>
    <tr id="zkComp119">
      <td id="zkComp120">
        <span class="z-label" id="zkComp121">Buscar por:</span>
      </td>
      <td id="zkComp122"></td>
      <td id="zkComp123"></td>
      <td id="zkComp124">
        <select id="zkComp118" selectedindex="0">
          <option id="zkComp125" selected="selected">Fecha de activación</option>
          <option id="zkComp127">Cliente</option>
          <option id="zkComp129">No. de Cliente</option>
          <option id="zkComp131">Contrato</option>
          <option id="zkComp133">Estatus</option>
          <option id="zkComp135">Distribuidor</option>
         </select>
        </td>
        <td id="zkComp137">
          <span class="z-label" id="zkComp94">Inicio:</span>
          <i class="z-datebox" id="zkComp142">
            <input class="z-datebox-inp" id="zkComp142-real" type="text" size="11" value="" autocomplete="off">
            <i class="z-datebox-btn" id="zkComp142-btn"></i>
            <div id="zkComp142-pp" style="display: none;"></div>|           </i>
          <span class="z-label" id="zkComp143">Fin:</span>
          <i class="z-datebox" id="zkComp144">
            <input class="z-datebox-inp" id="zkComp144-real" type="text" size="11" value="" autocomplete="off">
            <i class="z-datebox-btn" id="zkComp144-btn"></i>
            <div id="zkComp144-pp" style="display: none;"></div>              </i>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But if I manually click on the option that I need in the website, the last td in the code changes and looks like this

```html
<table id="tblFiltros">
<tbody>
  <tr id="zkComp119">
    <td id="zkComp120">
      <span class="z-label" id="zkComp121">Buscar por:</span>
    </td>
    <td id="zkComp122"></td>
    <td id="zkComp123"></td>
    <td id="zkComp124">
      <select id="zkComp118" selectedindex="0">
        <option id="zkComp125" selected="selected">Fecha de activación</option>
        <option id="zkComp127">Cliente</option>
        <option id="zkComp129">No. de Cliente</option>
        <option id="zkComp131">Contrato</option>
        <option id="zkComp133">Estatus</option>
        <option id="zkComp135">Distribuidor</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td id="zkComp137"><input class="z-textbox" id="zkComp97" type="text" value=""></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I´ve looked in other answers but I cant find something that works for my code.
I´ve already tried with FireEvent but I doesn´t change anything and also with getelementsbyID("").focus but still I can´t make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `HTMLDoc.getElementById("ID").FireEvent("onchange")`? I haven't worked with HTML in VBA but if it were javascript "onchange" would be the event that would fire whenever the selected option changes.

Comment: yes, I´ve tried that line with most of the id´s in the code but it still doesn´t change